# Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. Django Apache AWS

Tags: django, apache

on running 'python manage.py 0.0.0.0:8000' its working good but now after shifting on apache its showing permission error.

**sudo tail -100 /var/log/apache2/error.log**

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/home/ubuntu/env'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home/ubuntu/env'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home/ubuntu/env'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/home/ubuntu/env'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/home/ubuntu/env'
  sys.path = [
    '/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python310.zip',
    '/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.10',
    '/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
  ]

Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f45674e6780 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
[Wed Sep 06 17:41:35.663206 2023] [wsgi:warn] [pid 21214:tid 139936062662528] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=21214): Unable to stat Python home /home/ubuntu/env. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
```

**sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/proj/static
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/proj/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
        Alias /media /home/ubuntu/proj/media
        <Directory /home/ubuntu/proj/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
    <Directory /home/user/proj/proj>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess proj python-path=/home/ubuntu/proj python-home=/home/ubuntu/env
    WSGIProcessGroup proj
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/proj/proj/wsgi.py
```